# python / python3 - how to merge different locations for installed packages of anaconda and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, path, anaconda

It seems that I have several version of python installed on same computer, one from them being the `anaconda` distribution. However certain packages can be imported only with certain version of python. How can we merge all the source of packages:

I succesfully installed opencv and try to import it in a script from `Atom` with the command `import cv2` (1):

```
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libImath-2_2.12.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_4/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

**Importing with command `python` (the one linked to `anaconda`)**

I went then to the `Terminal` and called python with `$ python`

```
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr 6 2018, 13undefined09) 
GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) on darwin
```

I then tried to import open cv with `import cv2` and got the same error message as in (1) above

**Importing with command `python3`**

I then entered `import python3` (instead of `python`), it worked: I got:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03undefined55) GCC 4.2.1 (Apple 
Inc. build 5666) (dot 3) on darwin
```

And could execute a script with
    import cv2

apparently those 2 different command fetch the package from different locations because:`$ which python` get me `/anaconda3/bin/python` and `$ which python3` gets me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

As I use Atom as text editor, how can I make Atom to look at the correct place?

Many thanks in advance!

Specifications:

- macOS 10.14
- Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had actually to change the `Path` in the `.json` file of the jupyter kernel. First I checked the list of jupyter kernel:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
julia-0.6    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-0.6
julia-1.0    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
python3      /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I then `cd` the above python path and, I found the file `kernel.json` inside and opened it:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/path/to/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

In that file, I then changed the line `/path/to/python` by the python path I got when typing the following in Terminal:

```
$ which python
/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Relaunched `Atom` and it finally worked!

The hints of the [github page of jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) helped also a lot!